# Displaying excel 2010 worksheets as a looping slideshow

Tags: vba, excel-2010

Total novice here. Hoping someone can help 
 I am looking for a macro to display any Excel 2010 worksheets in my workbook as a looping slideshow. This is to be displayed on a tv display.

I came across the code below which is great but it stops at the last page and i have no requirement for the message box at the end

```
Sub StartSlideShow()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "ShowNextSheet"
End Sub

Sub ShowNextSheet()
    Dim lastIndex As Integer, nextShtIndex As Integer

    lastShtIndex = Worksheets.Count
    nextShtIndex = ActiveSheet.Index + 1

    If nextShtIndex <= lastShtIndex Then
        Worksheets(nextShtIndex).Select
        StartSlideShow
    Else
        MsgBox "End of slide show"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

This isn't "driving you crackers". This code is clearly copy and pasted from the internet, and you have put no effort into actually solving it your self.

Regardless, this should work;

```
If nextShtIndex <= lastShtIndex Then
    Worksheets(nextShtIndex).Select
    StartSlideShow
Else
    Worksheets(0).Select
    StartSlideShow
End If
```